# VS 2012 breaks on wrong thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, model-view-controller

I have a program which is multi-threaded, and in which I've set a number of breakpoints.  Frequently, when the program hits a breakpoint, I see a line of code highlighted in green, indicating that it is the next line of code to be executed when the program returns from the current function.  However, the breakpoint which has been hit is actually on another thread, in another source file.  This line is not highlighted in yellow (or anything else), despite being the thread which actually caused the break.

The only way I've found so far to fix the problem is to stop the program executing, clean the solution and rebuild the entire solution.  This is about 70% effective, but I frequently have to do it several times.

Additional info which may be relevant:  The program is written in C#, and the code in question is a WCF service being called by an MVC web site.  All this is running under IIS7 on my local machine.

Comment: You know that when execution is paused you can select which thread you're seeing the stacktrace/source code highlighting/all the rest of your info for.  It's annoying if it's not swapping to the thread that hit the breakpoint, but it's not like you need to rebuild/redeploy to see it, just open the "threads" tab and select it.

Comment: Actually, the thread that hit the break doesn't show up in the Threads window.

Answer (score 0):

You can go from one thread to the other in debug.

Debug \ Windows \ Threads [ctrl-alt-h]

You'll have the list of thread.

Be carefull, when stepping inside the code, you might alternate between threads. The best option is to freeze the other threads.